# "Cannot load script for execution" for script contains web reference in ssis package in console mode

Tags: ssis

I want to execute a script in case of any error occurrence in my package,When i run my package in `development mode`,every thing goes well,but when i put it on `task scheduler` or run it through `console` i run into this error for this specific script

> Cannot load script for execution

But when i `remove web reference` that is used for `sending Sms Message` and just put a text logger,every thing goes as supposed to be.

By the way i'm using visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out that the problem was originated from mismatching sql version of my Ssis package and version of sql that i was running through task scheduler .

I was running my package through following code

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f D:\Packages\....dtsx
```

I changed my package Sql Version from `Sql Server 2014` to `Sql Server 2016` as you see below

[image]